# Is there a way to get a list of all counters in perforce?

Tags: perforce

Perforce has a command called `counter`, based on its [manual](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_counter.html), you can get the value of a counter by running this command:

```
p4 counter mycounter
```

My question is if you don't know the name of the counter, is there a way to see what counters are available and set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p4 counters`

In most cases if there is a `p4 noun` command to operate on a `noun` there is a `p4 nouns` command to list all existing `nouns`.

`p4 branch`: `p4 branches`

`p4 change`: `p4 changes`

`p4 client` : `p4 clients`

`p4 counter`: `p4 counters`

`p4 depot`: `p4 depots`

`p4 fix`: `p4 fixes`

`p4 group`: `p4 groups`

`p4 job`: `p4 jobs`

`p4 label`: `p4 labels`

`p4 stream`: `p4 streams`

`p4 user`: `p4 users`

etc